# Laravel input loop

Tags: laravel, forms, loops, foreach

i try to looping my edit form. but the foreach loop doesn't work. anyone can help?

```html
@foreach($siswas as $siswa)
<form id="editform" action="{{route(siswa.update, $siswa->id}}" method="post">
        @method('PATCH')
        @csrf
      <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nama" class="col-form-label">Nama</label>
            <input type="text" value="{{$siswa->nama}}" id="nama" name="editNama" class="form-control" >
          </div>
      </div>
</form>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Please show your edit function code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several errors there:

- route name should be a string (in quotes),
- route parameter should be an associative array,
- in provided example, closing parenthesis missed

(Assuming that parameter in Route is `id`), try with

```
{{ route('siswa.update', ['id' => $siswa->id]) }}
```

[Laravel named routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#named-routes).

Comment: what about the input value, i tried to use 'old()' function but it didn't work

Comment: Problem is that you have same name for all fields in loop (i.e. editNama) field name is repeated. Maybe you would like to have distinct names there - for example to append it with `'_' . $siswa->id`.

Then you could try with `{{ optional(old('editNama_' . $siswa->id)) != null ? old('editNama_' . $siswa->id) : $siswa->nama }}`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

your edit function like this:

```
public function edit($id)
    {

        $siswas = Yourmodel::find($id);
        return view('yourviewpath',compact('siswas'));

    }
```

Your view file like this:

```
<form id="editform" action="{{route(siswa.update, [$siswas->id]}}" method="post">
        @method('PATCH')

        @csrf
      <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nama" class="col-form-label">Nama</label>
            <input type="text" value="{{ old('editNama', $siswas->nama) }}" id="nama" name="editNama" class="form-control" >
          </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should incorporate siswa in your form id:

```
@foreach($siswas as $siswa)
<form id="editform-{$siswa->id}" action="{{route(siswa.update, $siswa->id}}" method="post">
        @method('PATCH')
        @csrf
      <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nama-" class="col-form-label">Nama</label>
            <input type="text" value="{{$siswa->nama}}" id="nama" name="editNama" class="form-control" >
          </div>
      </div>
</form>
@endforeach
```